# How to setup APACHE, MYSQL SERVER, PHP on Windows 8.1?

Tags: networking, apache-http-server, php, mysql

Trying to setup a website server at home.

Been trying this for weeks, but to no avail. If someone can help I will indeed be grateful, and I will wire over some beers if necessary.

So, I have WINDOWS 8.1 pre-installed on my laptop which I dont want to change. Trawling through the web I have now discovered that Apache, MYSQL SERVER, and PHP are what I need. 
I know how to program fairly okay in SQL and in PHP, so that is no worry. I installed Apaache and PHP however nothing seems to work : when I type http://localhost, I get an "error/timeout" type message in any of my browsers - chrome/IE.
Below are the things I have done so far:

1) SETUP STATIC IP for one of my laptops like so:
    Router: D-Link-600 router
    "LAN Setup" -> DHCP Reservation, pulldown menu, selected one of my laptops, I typed in an IP such as 192.168.0.180 (so it locks down the IP on teh local area network)
    Save settings.

2) SETUP PORT FORWARDING for that laptop on the D-LINK-600 Router:
    Went to "ADVANCED" in the "router-page"
    "Application Name" -> Pull down menu -> "HTTP" then clicked '<<' arrow. 
    Public Port 80 ~ 80 automatically filled in. "Computer Name" -> Chose that same laptop -> IP Address filled in as the one I chose above 192.168.0.180
    Private Port 80 ~ 80 automatically filled in.

3) OPEN FIREWALL ON LAPTOP:
    First uninstalled McAfee coz it was preventing me from changing any settings, I didnt know if it was necessary but I uninstalled it anyway.
    Went to "Control Panel" -> "System and Security" -> "Windows firewall"
    Private Networks: Turn off windows Firewall
    Public Networks: Turn off windows Firewall

4) Allow incoming stuff on PORT 80 on LAPTOP:
    Same place - Windows Firewall and Advanced Settings : Inbound Rule : New rule : PORT : Selected TCP and Specified New Port as 80 : Allow Connection : Domain Private Public : Name"PORT80" : FINISH

Went to website: yougetsignal to see if port 80 is open - it shows me my "internet" IP (different from locally fixed IP as above) and says PORT 80 is closed (due to "Timeout")

5) APACHE INSTALLATION:
    My "SYSTEM" in control panel is 64 bit operating system.
    Downloaded from Apachelounge.com/download/  httpd-2.4.17-win64-VC14.zip
    Extraced into C:/Apache24

```
httpd.conf have the following lines:
```

httpd.conf additional/altered lines::: start

```
ServerRoot "c:/Apache24"

Listen 192.168.0.180:80

LoadModule php5_module "c:/php/php5apache2_4.dll"

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php

# If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.

#

ServerName Localhost:80      -> was ServerName www.example.com:80, i changed it to Localhost:80

<IfModule dir_module>

        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

</IfModule>

PHPIniDir c:/php
```

httpd.conf additional/altered lines::: end

6) PHP Installation?
    Renamed the "php.ini-development" file to "php.ini"
    Opened it, and enabled some extensions like CURL, MYSQL, etc.
    OUt of curiosity, I ran the file php.exe in c:php folder (all extracted), and it says   MSVCR110.dll file is missing.

7) PUTTING IT ALL TO WORK TOGETHER:

Ran the CMD prompt in Administrator mode. It said some VC***110.dll file is missing - downloaded that, it worked.

however, now the CMD prompt upon installation (c:\Apache24> httpd.exe -k install  ) says: 
"Syntax error on line 178 of C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load c:/php/php5apache2_4.dll into server: %1 is not a valid win32 application.

went to the APache/bin folder and ran httpd.exe 
went to IE/Chrome and tuped http://Localhost

NOTHING. Just timeout. I Need Help guys.

PLEASE. HELP.

Comment: Did you try xampp ?

Comment: Its a bit more work, but I'd seriously suggest getting something like virtualbox up and running a full lamp stack on top of that. Also, I think windows 8/10 has some internal stuff running on port 80.

Comment: Skype often listens on 80 and 443 so if that's running, it may be the first place too look... As others have, and although they may not be "production secure", you can use WAMP/XAMPP but just make sure you only forward port 80 from your router... As @JourneymanGeek has pointed out, you *could* run a virtual machine with *just* Linux on and install a LAMP stack so that your "webserver" is ring-fenced from the rest of your LAN...

Comment: I was thinking modern UI apps. Close enough tho. Some ISPs also block port 80... which can also be a pain, come to think of it.

Comment: It looks like you did the port forwarding correctly _I think_ So it may well be that your ISP is blocking port 80

Comment: Try changing the forwarding so that incomming port 8080 is forwarded to internal port 80. Then try accessing your WAN ip:8080. If that works then its probably the ISP blocking port 80

Answer (score 0):

You could try any of the following:

1. [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html)
2. [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/#download-wrapper)
3. set up http.conf to use a different port in the private use range(49152–65535)